# Google Tag Manager Integration for Magento Checkout Success

Tags: magento, google-tag-manager

I'm a bit confused with getting around on what GTM mentions as to the following.

> The rule is considered matched only when every condition below is satisfied.

**Screenshot**
[image]

My magento checkout success page might end up in different URLs depending on the order. Listing a few below.

- **http**://domain.com/checkout/onepage/success/
- **https**://domain.com/checkout/onepage/success/
- **http**://domain.com/checkout/multishipping/success/
- **https**://domain.com/checkout/multishipping/success/

Now the above four can be **without the trailing slash** as well, which sums to 8 URLs.

I'm aware that I can't add all these URL matches to a single rule with the GTM {{url}} contains or  {{url}} equals parameters.

What's the best way to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use two rules

1. url contains checkout

and

2. url contains success

Comment: Cool, I have edited the answer so it only has the one that worked. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem. Thanks